# $p_k \colon M_k \to N_k$ is onto for $k>0$, if $p_0$ induces an iso on homology level, prove that $p_0$ is onto

Tags: homological-algebra, exact-sequence

We are working in $\textbf{Ch}_R$, chain complexes of $R-$modules.

> As the title suggest, I'm given a map (of chain complexes) $p\colon M \to N$ which is onto for $k>0$. It is known that $(p_k)_*\colon H_*M \to H_*N$ is an isomorphism, prove that $p_0 \colon M_0 \to N_0$ is onto as well. The hint says that it should be a consequence of the five lemma.

**MY wrong ATTEMPT** consider the commutative diagram given by two s.e.s $$0 \rightarrow B_1(M_0) \hookrightarrow Z_0(M_0) \rightarrow H_0(M)$$ and $$0 \rightarrow B_1(N_0) \hookrightarrow Z_0(N_0) \rightarrow H_0(N)$$  and vertical arrows induced by $p$. but then even if I'm able to prove that the hypothesis of the four lemma are met, I'd obtain that $p_0$ restricted to the cycles is surjective. I don't know which other exact sequence I can use. For example, the l.e.s. on homology is useless, because I already know that on homology level $(p_0)_*$ is onto.

So the point is that I don't know how to relate the hypothesis on the homology level with the fact that $p_0 \colon M_0 \to N_0$ is onto. 
any hints?

Comment: Do your chain complexes have non zero terms in negative degree?

Comment: @DBS good question, this points came up because I'm reading an article by Dwyer-Spalinski about Model cats. and another one of Hovey, about model cats. as well. In the first the chain complexes are indexed by the naturals in the second one it's indexed by the integers. I'd assume that it's indexed by the naturals (and extended by zero eventually)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so the idea is that the map $M_0 \to N_0$ will be onto on $H_0$ and also hit the image which is quotiened out. (assuming the chain complex is bounded at zero)

Since chain maps commute with the boundary operators and $M_1 \to N_1$ is onto, we know that $im(M_0 \to N_0)= im(N_1 \to N_0)$. We have an isomorphism on homology so we know $M_0/im(M_1 \to M_0) \to N_0/im(N_1 \to N_0)$ an isomorphism. Can you try to take it from here?

Comment: Thank you Dan, actually there are two points which I don't get very well. First how do you prove the equality about the two images $im(M_0\to N_0)=im(N_1\to N_0)$. Using commutativity+onto I can prove that $im(N_1\to N_0)=im(M_1\to N_0)$ but I cannot go any further. (Do I need surjectivity of $M_1\to M_0$?).
Second point, even assuming that, I have no idea on how to proceed from the two quotients, can you give me some more hints?

Comment: Ok, I think I worked out a proof, could you check if it is correct? By the fact that on homology level $p_0$ is onto, we have that $\forall c_0 \in N_0$, up to a border we have $p_0(y_0)=c_0+\partial c_1$, but now $p_1$ is onto by hip, hence $p_0(y_0)=c_0+\partial p_1(y_1) = c_0+p_0\partial (y_1) $, and hence a pre image of a $c_0$ is $y_0-\partial y_1$